# Proper factoring when generating files with XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, xslt-1.0

In a particular segment of a system I'm working on, we are generating PDF and HTML files using XSLT (for email, print and display.) The business model being printed is in code (c#).

When designing the schema, I made special considerations for the requirements of the printed documents as XSLT is much more difficult (possibly just for me?) to work with than C#. For example, I generate aggregate values and tables from the business model for display on the document. These decisions don't translate well to other areas where similar Xml might be used.

I'm now facing a problem of others using the Xml as well and therefore breaking SoC.

I'm leaning towards taking a snapshot of the Xml they originally latched on to and giving them a new method. I personally don't see a problem with this (in the face of DRY), but others might have a hard time understanding the trade-off. Is my reasoning flawed? Is there a better approach?

Comment: A quick way to summarise this might be: Is there value in avoiding anything but trivial processing in XSLT and generating idiomatic Xml to support the approach?

Comment: In general, I would argue that XSL is an extremely power projection and mapping tool, moreso even than LINQ (as we don't even require the overhead of Deserialization and POCO creation). The one limitation is Grouping in XSLT 1.0 (i.e. the requirement for Muenchian grouping or hacks with following::sibling), and possibly also shortfalls in string and date formatting functionality. This limitation is overcome in XSLT 2+, but unfortunately this isn't much help in .Net. Note also that in .Net you can use the `msxsl` extensions.

Comment: @StuartLC Thanks. Would your approach be to generalise the Xml so that it's decoupled from the XSLT? I undestand this approach but it has come across to me as unworkable and not entirely pragmatic

Comment: We are speaking at a very vague / general level which isn't really on topic of SO. Can you possibly come up with a more concrete / definite example of where you feel you are violating SoC. XSL needs the same principles as any other code, e.g. DRYing up and refactoring code into reusable call-templates, breaking up large XSL's into includes / imports etc etc.

Comment: @Sprague If that's your response to people who are trying to help you, I'll be moving along too.

Comment: @Sprague It doesn't matter if your question makes sense. "Making sense" is a necessary, but not a sufficient criterion for being on-topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This question clearly is off-topic, because it invites open-ended discussion. That, and what michael.hor257k says.

Comment: @StuartLC there are at least two excellent XSLT 2.0 processors for .NET: Saxon and XmlPrime.

Comment: @StuartLC With this question, I was hoping to get a variety of answers and votes which could show a group consensus, or examples pointing to best practices. I find SO community has a tendency to try to mutate the question to be more comfortable for them to answer. Perhaps I'm not clear, but I'm happy with the level of generality of the question.

Comment: And as far as trying to help me- you're trying to get points, and you did by having your retort up-voted, so you got rewarded! Congrats! You should be thanking me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a personal thing, but my choice would always be to put as much of the logic as possible in the XSLT code rather than the C# code - the opposite of what you are doing. It means you're working in a higher-level declarative language, and one that is expressly designed for manipulating XML. There is a learning curve, of course, but at the top of the learning curve you will find sunlit uplands. And don't allow yourself to be put off by the limitations of XSLT 1.0: 2.0 leaves all those problems behind, you just have to be prepared to ditch Microsoft and use third-party technology (Microsoft stopped doing anything new in the XML space about a decade ago, but that doesn't mean you have to stay stuck in the past).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is probably where I'm leaning now after sitting on it a few days. I don't like the answer because it means having to use more XSLT, but hey ho. I don't find it to be the sunlit uplands you describe, but thanks!